# Accessing a JSON object in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I currently have a JSON object that my program creates dynamically. The object is valid and can be parsed with JSON.parse().

This is the object i am working with:

```
{
    "1":
        {
                "name":"temporary",
                "value":"5" 
        },
    "2":
        {
                "name":"temporary 2",
                "value":"10"
        }
}
```

The code i am trying to use is:

```
              var obj = JSON.parse(StringObj);
              var count = Object.keys(obj).length;
              for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
                console.log(obj[i].name + ": " + obj[i].value);
              }
```

However, this is throwing an error in the console:

`obj[i] is undefined`

What am i doing wrong here? ive done this a thousand times before in different applications but cant figure out why it isn't working this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop starts at `0`, yet the keys are `1` and `2`. You need to loop from `1` instead:

```js
var obj = {
  "1": { "name": "temporary", "value": "5" },
  "2": { "name": "temporary 2", "value": "10" }
}

var count = Object.keys(obj).length;
for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
  console.log(obj[i].name + ": " + obj[i].value);
}
```

Alternatively you can avoid the issue by using a `forEach()` loop over the keys:

```js
var obj = {
  "1": { "name": "temporary", "value": "5" },
  "2": { "name": "temporary 2", "value": "10" }
}

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
  console.log(obj[key].name + ": " + obj[key].value);
});
```

Comment: This worked. Cheers for that. however, My keys will not always be in order, for example if there are three items and the second is deleted, the keys will be 1 and 3. how can I get round this?

Comment: @DarrylWhalley in that case use the second method I showed as it loops over the keys no matter what order or value they have.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks for that!